# Функция для считывания данных из файла с расширением txt

Tags: c++, файлы, printf, scanf

Имеются две функции. Одна записывает данные в файл другая считывает. При записи всё отрабатывает хорошо. При считывании происходит ошибка доступа. Подскажите в чём ошибка.

```
void Func_zap(CARD_INDEX*k)
{
    FILE* f;
    fopen_s(&f,"my.txt", "w+");

    if (f)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
           
            fprintf_s(f,"Автор:%s\nНазвание:%-15s\nГод издания:%-15d\nСтоимость:%-15.2f\nКатегория:%-15s\n",pB[i]->author, pB[i]->name, pB[i]->year, pB[i]->price, pB[i]->strCategory[pB[i]->category]);
           
        }
    }
    else
    {
    std::cout << "Не удалось открыть файл";
    }
    fclose(f);
}

void Func_fail(CARD_INDEX* k) {
    FILE* f;
    fopen_s(&f, "my.txt", "r");
    if (f)
    {
        
            pB[count] = new BOOK;
            fscanf_s(f, "Автор:%s\nНазвание:%s\nГод издания:%d\nСтоимость:%.2f\nКатегория:%d\n", pB[count]->author,pB[count]->name, &pB[count]->year, &pB[count]->price, &pB[count]->strCategory[pB[count]->category]);
         
            count++;
            quantity++;
           //printf_book(pB[count]);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Не удалось открыть файл";
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: Вы в курсе, что при записи `%s` — это вся строка, а при чтении — *одно слово*?

Comment: Нет. Первый раз слышу.

Comment: Ну, теперь знаете :) Но я не смотрел внимательно всё, и утверждать, что ошибка *только* в этом, не стану.

Comment: А как правильно писать? Необходимо s заменить на что то другое?

Comment: Меня ещё беспокоит вопрос, правильно ли я, при выделении памяти указал к ней доступ.

Comment: Читать всю строку — с помощью `fgets()`. Выделения памяти я в исходниках не вижу.

Comment: Вот я выделяю память под структуру в которую хочу в последствии записать  pB[count] = new BOOK;

Comment: А! да, не заметил. Ну, надо еще знать, что такое `BOOK` и как описано `pB`.

Comment: struct BOOK
{
 char author[10];       //автор
 char name[80];       //название
 unsigned int year;         //год издания
 float price;       //цена
 eCategory category;        //категория
 const char* strCategory[4] = { "PROSE", "POESY", "SCIENCE", "UNDEF" };
 
};

Comment: size_t quantity = 10;// количество книг в картотеке.
BOOK** pB= new BOOK * [quantity];//создаём динамический массив указателей на книги.
size_t capacity = 10;//количество резервных указателей
size_t count = 0; //актуальное количество книг в картотеке
struct CARD_INDEX* k; //создали указатель на картатеку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очередная жесть.

1. Зачем вы используете функции языка Cи в С++? Вы уж определитесь вы на C++ или на классическом Си пишете. Ваш код выглядит как "Крутой пацан в ферари, а с ним рядом на сидении сидит старая морщинистая бабка"
2. Если используете "русские буквы", то обязательно надо использовать wstring. Это избавляет от кучи багов. Старые методы не умеют работать с long char кодировками.
3. Зачем использовать пойнтеры и массивы?! Когда в плюсах есть отличная вещь как list???!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct {
    string author;
    string book;
    unsigned short published;
    float price;
    string category;
} Bookshelf;

list<Bookshelf> bookshelf;

void add(string author, string book, unsigned short published, float price, string category) {
    Bookshelf item = *(new Bookshelf());
    item.author = author;
    item.book = book;
    item.published = published;
    item.price = price;
    item.category = category;
    bookshelf.push_back(item);
}

void freemem(void) {
    bookshelf.clear();
}

int main(void) {

    add("Vasilij Pupkin", "Kniga", 1990, 20, "Hlam");
    add("Tester", "testie", 1991, 10.5, "Hlam");
    // write out
    ofstream out("output.txt");
    for (auto book: bookshelf) {
        out << book.author << endl << book.book << endl
            << book.published << endl << book.price << endl
            << book.category << endl;
    }
    freemem();
    out.flush();
    out.close();
    // read in
    string author, book, published, price, category;
    ifstream in("output.txt");
    while (!in.eof()) {
        if (getline(in, author) && getline(in, book) &&
            getline(in, published) && getline(in, price) &&
            getline(in, category))
        {
            add(author, book, stoi(published), stof(price), category);
        }
    }
    in.close();
    // list
    for (auto book: bookshelf) {
        cout << "Author: " << book.author << endl
            << "Book: " << book.book << endl
            << "Published: " << book.published << endl
            << "Price: " << book.price << endl
            << "Category: " << book.category << endl << endl;
    }
    freemem();
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод.

```
root@__server__:/__path__/writefile# ./writer
Author: Vasilij Pupkin
Book: Kniga
Published: 1990
Price: 20
Category: Hlam

Author: Tester
Book: testie
Published: 1991
Price: 10.5
Category: Hlam

root@__server__:/__path__/writefile# cat output.txt
Vasilij Pupkin
Kniga
1990
20
Hlam
Tester
testie
1991
10.5
Hlam
```

Comment: Я не волшебник, я только учусь.))))) И к тому же ограничен рамками задания. Вот и привинчиваю к С++ СИ и наоборот. Благодарю за ответ. Сейчас попробую адаптировать под своё задание.)))

Comment: У нас на криптографии препод за плюсы карал. Если ни дай бог где-то плюсик проскочит, то автоматом отчисление. Сейчас уже 30+ лет, и до сих пор на плюсах не пишу. Люблю старенький добренький Си ))) А вообще std::string и std::list если пишешь в статике, это это такие добрые заботливые девушки которые все утечки памяти за тобой приберут и сделают всё Okey! =)

Comment: Это замечательно.)))) Но мы сейчас изучаем scanf и printf. Нужно пройти этим тернистым путём, чтоб оценить всю прелесть std::string и std::list

Comment: Тогда советую взять на заметку вот этот вот пост, там реализация большинства необходимого на старом добром C99 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1355060/Создание-списка-слов-с-последующим-удалением-дубликатов-последнего-слова-в-Си/1355127#1355127

Comment: Меб разобраться, как сюда привинтить fscanf_s.

Comment: Я линканул выше, там и fgets и fputs есть, и создание динамического массива.

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Очень интересно.